# Exception calling remote SOAP call from thread

Tags: web-services, multithreading, delphi, soap

This is an extension / next step of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538655/should-i-free-a-delphi-object-auto-instantiated-from-a-web-services-call) I asked a few minutes ago.

I've a Delphi application with a main form and a thread.  Every X seconds the thread makes a web services request for a remote object. It then posts back to the main form which handles updating the UI with the new information.

I was previously using a TTimer object in my thread, and when the TTimer callback function ran, it ran in the context of the main thread (but the remote web services request did work).  This rather defeated the purpose of the separate thread, and so I now have a simple loop and sleep routine in my thread's Execute function.  The problem is, an exception is thrown when returning from GetIMySOAPService().

```
procedure TPollingThread.Execute;
var
SystemStatus : TCWRSystemStatus;
begin
while not Terminated  do
begin
  sleep(5000);
  try
    SystemStatus := GetIMySOAPService().GetSystemStatus;
    PostMessage( ParentHandle, Integer(apiSystemStatus), Integer(SystemStatus), 0 );
    SystemStatus.DataContext := nil;
    LParam(SystemStatus) := 0;
  except
  end;
end;
end;
```

Can anyone advise as to why this exception is being thrown when calling this function from the thread? I'm sure I'm overlooking something fundamental and simple.

Thanks, Duncan

Comment: You should post the exception class and message too.

Comment: The exception class is EOleException, and the message is "CoInitialize has not been called"... which has solved my problem as this will be needed, I think, by the XML engine.

Comment: I assumed that much. Doing anything OLE-related requires `CoInitialize()` to be called. The main VCL thread does it itself, in the initialization of OLE units, for all other threads the programmer has to do it.

Comment: Not directly related, but another problem that I see is that there is a good chance that this will fire off another SOAP request after the thread has been signaled to terminate. IMO, if Terminated is true, then you should not perform any lengthy operations. You could move the Sleep(5000) to the bottom of the loop,  or you could guard the "try" with "if not Terminated then try".

Comment: @Chris: True, but that would still block program termination for up to 5 seconds. The simple solution to that is to call `Sleep(100)` or similar in a loop, and check `Terminated` in each iteration. Another way would be to call `SleepEx()` and queue an APC (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681951%28VS.85%29.aspx) when the thread needs to terminate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Execute()` method, you must call `CoInitialize` and `CoUnitialize` to setup and tear down the COM library.

Your main thread automatically does this in the `Application.Initialize()` procedure, however, other threads require the call to `CoInitialize` before calling COM functions.

Ensure you call `CoInitialize` in the `Execute()` method and not in the constructor because the constructor is executed in the parent thread (usually the main thread). That's not where you need it. It must be called from the thread that you plan on making COM calls from.

I recommend using this format:

```
try
  // OleCheck will raise an error if the call fails
  OleCheck(CoInitializeEx(NIL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED or COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY));
  try
    // Do work here
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
except
  // We failed, do something
end;
```

This allows you to trap the error if it fails to initialize and ensures that you call `CoUninitialize`.

Comment: +1 for calling `CoUninitialize()` only when `CoInitializeEx()` succeeded, and for having a top-level exception handler in the thread.

Comment: mghie, I know that I have a mis-matched Co/CoUn in my app, as I threw CoInitialize in there because that's what the error said to do.... I will fix at the first opportunity, but that'll usually be a change request or escalated bug.  In the meantime, what sort of problems will I be looking at?  A memory leak, or will it crash somehow, or will it just be benign?

Comment: @Chris: I don't know for sure, I expect it to be benign, maybe some windows and handles not being properly released. Still, I like to vote up answers that promote good practices, and the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543%28VS.85%29.aspx) clearly states that calls need to be balanced to gracefully close the COM library.

Comment: Thanks mghie, I'll fix at the earliest convenience, and it's good to know that it probably isn't too serious.

Answer (score 2):

For my future-self...I needed to CoInitialize and CoUnInitialize in my Execute method:

```
procedure TPollingThread.Execute;
begin

  CoInitialize(nil);

  while not Terminated  do
  begin
  // ...
  end;


   CoUnInitialize;
end;
```

Comment: And may I also suggest reading the error messages. They might contain hidden hints :)