# Delphi webservice call not in parallel

Tags: web-services, delphi, parallel-processing

I developed an application that get messages through TCP server in parallel and calls a webservice from another webserver application.

I noted that parallel requests processed by webservice server in serial.

I forced webserver to have delay in response to enhance situation.

I traced and found that webservice calls are in parallel by low level  Delphi webserivce call serialize calls.

I sniffed and found only one connection is opened and HTTP requests are sent one by one after getting response.

My base web service call is as bellow

```
var  
  HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO;  
  WS: TelephoneDispachServerSoap;  
begin  
  try  
    HTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);  
    WS := GetTelephoneDispachServerSoap(false, '',HTTPRIO);  
    CoInitialize(nil);  
    r := WS.MaxMethod(10,20);  
  finally  
    CoUninitialize;  
  end;  
end;
```

What Should I do to send webservice calls in parallel?
Thanks

Comment: Does the rest of the code do something in the VCL main thread, for example using synchronize?

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2540915/80901) answer: use `OleCheck(CoInitializeEx(NIL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED or COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY));` and handle exceptions with try / except